# Javadoc no longer displays formatted tables

Tags: javadoc

I just updated to eclipse Mars1 version and Java 1.8
All my previous projects work except for javadoc that now displays a less than pleasant view. The problem is this: the javadoc used to display the class information in nice table form when I clicked on any of the html files. Now they display the text but the nice table view is not there. I'm sure it's now a requirement to check a setup checkbox somewhere but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you on Linux?  There's some native library that's missing from a default Eclipse installation, the absence of which causes Javadoc tooltips to display incorrectly.  I'm sorry I can't be more helpful than that.  It's been a long time since I've used Eclipse.

Comment: Kevin, Thanks for the response. No I am using Windows 7. Basically the same computer I used last year for this. This is just the basic javadoc use for documenting the classes. The html files appear in the subdirectory Doc after javadoc is generated. I have replicated it on computers in a school lab after the Eclipse Mars and Java jre1.8.0_66 were installed. I thought that javadoc.exe was part of the jre installation and not part of Eclipse. Am i in correct in that assumption?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the generated HTML look in a browser?

Comment: Good question. This morning I opened the index.html in IE and got the following (I did a copy/paste from the browser). I wanted to insert a jpeg but I don't see the option to do that.  Skip navigation links
Package 
Class 
Use 
Tree 
Deprecated 
Index 
Help 
Prev Package 
Next Package 
Frames 
No Frames 
All Classes 
Package cse1102.geometry
Class Summary  Class Description 
AllTests   
Circle Circle Class 
GeometryApp   
Recorder   
Rectangle Rectangle Class 
RectangleTest   
Shape   
Triangle Rectangle Class 
TriangleTest   
   

Skip navigation links